# How to insert content from another Custom Post type into Post?

Tags: php, mysql, html, wordpress

Say I have a custom post type called "Performers". This gets filled with different bands/performers with a featured image as well as custom fields (mp3 file, facebook link, myspace link, etc).

I have another custom post type called "Events".

When I create a new Event, I would like the option to have a drop box to select one of the bands from the "Performers" custom post type.

This will insert all data from the specific Band/Performer into the Event post (custom fields, featured image, etc.).

What is the best method to approach this?

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish something like that on another project -- see: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7199/sub-sub-blogs-creating-and-importing-content-into-a-custom-sub-type. Apparently the dev I'm working with figured it out. I'll ask him what he did tomorrow and add an answer here (And update that question as well).

Answer (score 1):

a little bit of jQuery

```
jQuery("#dropdown").change(function() {
    jQuery.getJSON(
        ajaxurl,
        {action: "get_band_info", band: jQuery("#dropdown").val()},
        function(data) {
           jQuery("#facebook").val(data.facebook);
        }
    );
}):
```

and a little bit of php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_band_info', 'my_get_band_info');

function my_get_band_info() {
    echo json_encode(array(
        'facebook' => get_post_meta($_POST['band'], 'facebook', 'true')
    ));
    exit();
}
```

Should do the trick.